# How to throw cowrie shells

Tags: dice

I saw a game being played at a party where they were using cowrie shells as the dice. While some players rolled random numbers during their turns, others seem to be almost preternaturally good at getting the rolls they want.

Is there a technique to throwing the shells?

Comment: Whilst not answering how to throw them you might want to look at this question. 
 https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/fairness-of-cowry-shells-as-dice  where answers suggest that are not fair, ie 50/50